# How to get the value of the artist name from this JSON object?

Tags: java, json

I have the following JSON object (sorry for the length) which I need to get the name of the artists. It should be under tracks -> items -> album -> artists -> name. I am trying to run this code but I can't grab the artist name. Here is part of the JSON object:

```
{
  "tracks" : {
    "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?query=closer&type=track&offset=0&limit=20",
    "items" : [ {
      "album" : {
        "album_type" : "single",
        "artists" : [ {
          "external_urls" : {
            "spotify" : "https://open.spotify.com/artist/69GGBxA162lTqCwzJG5jLp"
          },
          "href" : "https://api.spotify.com/v1/artists/69GGBxA162lTqCwzJG5jLp",
          "id" : "69GGBxA162lTqCwzJG5jLp",
          "name" : "The Chainsmokers",
          "type" : "artist",
          "uri" : "spotify:artist:69GGBxA162lTqCwzJG5jLp"
        } ],
        "available_markets" : [ "AD", "AR", "AT", "AU", "BE", "BG", "BO", "BR", "CA", "CH", "CL", "CO", "CR", "CY", "CZ", "DE", "DK", "DO", "EC", "EE", "ES", "FI", "FR", "GB", "GR", "GT", "HK", "HN", "HU", "ID", "IE", "IS", "IT", "JP", "LI", "LT", "LU", "LV", "MC", "MT", "MX", "MY", "NI", "NL", "NO", "NZ", "PA", "PE", "PH", "PL", "PT", "PY", "SE", "SG", "SK", "SV", "TR", "TW", "US", "UY" ],
```

.....

I need to get the line where it says `"name" : "The Chainsmokers",`, but I can't figure it out. This is what I have so far:

```
JSONObject jObj;
JSONObject tracks;
JSONArray items;
JSONObject album;
JSONArray artists;
JSONObject aName;
jObj = new JSONObject(json);
tracks = (JSONObject) jObj.get("tracks");
items = (JSONArray) tracks.get("items");
String songName;
Log.d("searchSong", json);
// Return all of the results for the searched song. This will return to a ListView with the song name, uri, and artist name.
for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
    try {
        songName = items.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
        if (!(songName.toLowerCase().contains(query.toLowerCase()))) {
            continue;
        }
        // TODO THIS DOESN'T WORK!!!!
        // How do I get artistname????
        album = (JSONObject) items.getJSONObject(i).get("album");
        artists = album.getJSONArray("artists");    // get the artist name
        String artistsName = artists.getJSONObject(4).toString();
        String artistName = "";
        artistName = artists.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");

        // This stuff works
        id = items.getJSONObject(i).getString("id");
        lViewSearch.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        lView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        bNext.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        bPlay.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        searchSongs.add(songName + "\n" + id);
        searchAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        svSong.clearFocus();
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} // end for loop
```

This is in a for loop because I need to get all of the songs, here I only posted the JSON object for part of it. Let me know if you see any problems, thanks!

Comment: Does it throw any error?  What are you getting instead?  Seems like a standard debugging problem.  Putting a breakpoint will help you.  Also, `String artistsName = artists.getJSONObject(4).toString();`, you might want to try with the index 3.  Just a hunch.

Comment: Can you not find a Java API for Spotify?

Comment: I've been dealing with that for a long time, it's unfinished, and not even made by spotify so it's very hard to get working for me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What is `artists.getJSONObject(4)`? Your array only seems to show one object in the array.

Should just be...

```
artists.getJSONObject(0).getString("name")
```

Comment: The getJSONObject(4) was because the "name" was the 4th object in artists JSONArray. And it actually should have been getJSONObject(3), forgot it's 0 indexed.

Comment: @Michael "*because the "name" was the 4th object in artists JSONArray*, " actually, no. It was the fourth key in the **first object of the array**. Need to check the brackets more carefully. JSON keys are unordered, so getting one by index doesn't work.